# ubuntu gnome 16.04 cannot shutdown but can reboot

Tags: shutdown, ubuntu-gnome

Recently I install the Ubuntu-gnome 16.04 on my Gateway laptop,but Problems happen when I try to shutdown it,the button doesn't work,the computer hangs on with the logo screen.but it can reboot.

I had use these commands
     `sudo halt`,
     `sudo shutdown -P now`,
     `init 0`,
     `systemd poweroff`
and so on,hower most of the above  also stop on the log screen,excepting the halt command quickly hangs on  a black screen with outputs:

> [539.532340]reboot:system halted

I take some log files in /var/log/syslog when I close the computer

```
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H systemd[1]: Stopping Session 1 of user ljhui.
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H gnome-session[832]: gnome-session-binary[832]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H gnome-session[832]: gnome-session-binary[832]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H gnome-session-binary[832]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user gdm.
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H gnome-session-binary[832]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H systemd[813]: Stopped target Default.
May  9 17:24:28 ljhui-NV47H rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="599" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

it always say the fail whale is dead ,how can I fix it ,anyone can help me ? thanks!

Comment: The command I use to shut down my computer is `sudo shutdown -h now`. Maybe is equivalent to the ones you posted, I don't know.

Comment: yes,I also use this command ,it behaves similarly